# canvas.drawCircle sometimes working, sometimes not

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw

I bought the book Programming Android, and it's a little confusing and disappointing on how they have different code in their Github (https://github.com/bmeike/ProgrammingAndroid2Examples/tree/master/AndroidUIDemo) and their book. I'm stuck in an example that teaches how to draw a circle in a random point, with the color that is assigned to the button, like, when I click the RED button, it should draw a red circle in a view.

I did some extra code and somehow I managed to get it working. Here is my onDraw method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
paint.setColor(hasFocus() ? Color.BLUE : Color.GRAY);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, paint);

    if (this.points == null) return;

    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    for (Point p : points.getAllPoints())
    {
        paint.setColor(p.getColor());
        canvas.drawCircle(p.getX(), p.getY(), 
                  p.getDiameter(), paint);
    }
}
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes not, BUT when it works, it draws a thin, large oval shape.

`p.getDiameter()` is ALWAYS **6**. Even if I put it to a fixed 6, the effect is the same.

Also, there is some strange thing happening: If I replace `p.getY()` and `p.getX()` by  `50`, it will never draw anything on the screen. 50 should not be out of the screen bounds.

In the image below you can see what it's being rendered and some code I use to create the views.

[image: my results]

Here is some extra relevant code.

Setting the pointView size (the place where I draw points):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    pointView.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(root.getWidth(), root.getHeight()/2));
}
```

Add an OnCLickListener to the button, so when I click it, it should draw a circle.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() //I'll not put the Red button here, for the sake of brevity.
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            makeDot(pointModel, pointView, Color.GREEN);
        }
    });
```

And the makeDot method:

```
private final Random rnd = new Random();
void makeDot(Points points, PointView pointView, int color)
{
    points.addPoint(
            rnd.nextFloat()*pointView.getWidth(),
            rnd.nextFloat()*pointView.getHeight(),
            color, POINT_DIAMETER /*always 6*/);

}
```

(I think POINT_DIAMETER should be POINT_RADIUS but it's OK for now.)

So, how can I get it to draw a round circle in a random position in the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ideas:

In addPoint, try generating the coordinates like this:

```
points.addPoint(
            rnd.nextInt() % pointView.getWidth(),
            rnd.nextInt() % pointView.getHeight(),
            color, POINT_DIAMETER /*always 6*/);
```

In your onClick method, try adding a call to invalidate:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() //I'll not put the Red button here, for the sake of brevity.
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            makeDot(pointModel, pointView, Color.GREEN);
            pointView.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

When you set the Style.FILL, set the color as well:

```
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(hasFocus() ? Color.BLUE : Color.GRAY);
```

Also, remove this line of code:

```
pointView.setScaleX(20);
```

That's all I could think of for now.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I got the same results, but the % instead of * made it even more difficult to render something, maybe because some values are < 0.

I posted an update to my question, with a screenshot, take a look :D

Comment: remove the setScaleX(50) line! That's what causing your circles to be stretched like that

Comment: I think it's something related to the size of the PointView, maybe it's stretching "far ahead" in the X axis. Because, as you can see, the circles are ovals in my screenshot, stretched in the X axis. And I don't know what to do to fix it :(

Comment: when you write pointView.setScaleX(20), you're basically telling the whole view to stretch everything 20 times its original proportion on the X axis. Remove this line of code.

Comment: Why ON EARTH did I wrote that? Seriously.... Maybe I was trying to set the width, until I remembered I can do it using LayoutParameters. This was stupid. Thanks, bro!